# Raspberry Pi Pico 64 color VGA

Tags: c, raspberry-pi-pico

I have found [these examples](https://vanhunteradams.com/Pico/VGA/VGA.html) from Hunter Adams to generate a VGA signal using the Raspberry Pi Pico. It is a simple setup that I want to extend. It uses only 3 pins for the RGB colors so it is able to use 8 colors. I added 3 more pins 2 for each channel so that I can generate 64 colors. To make it work I used a lower resolution (640x350) because otherwise it is using too much memory (307.2 KB while the Pico only has 264KB).

Hunter Adams crams two pixels in a byte because he is only using 3 bits per pixel. I'm using 6 bits so I can only get one pixel in there but this way I'm wasting 2 bits in every byte (76.8KB). So I came up with an idea it should be possible to cram 5 pixels in a 32-bit unsigned integer it should be possible to setup the DMA to pass 32-bit unsigned integers to the pio program. So I changed my program to do that but something in my code must be incorrect because it does not work.

Here is my vga.c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "hardware/pio.h"
#include "hardware/dma.h"
#include "hsync.pio.h"
#include "vsync.pio.h"
#include "rgb.pio.h"

#define H_ACTIVE 655   // 640+16-1
#define V_ACTIVE 479   // 480-1
#define RGB_ACTIVE 127 // 640/5-1
#define RED_PIN 0
#define HSYNC 6
#define VSYNC 7
#define TXCOUNT 61440

uint32_t vga_data_array[TXCOUNT];
uint32_t *address_pointer = &vga_data_array[0];

void drawPixel(int x, int y, char color)
{
    if (x > 639)
        x = 639;
    if (x < 0)
        x = 0;
    if (y < 0)
        y = 0;
    if (y > 479)
        y = 479;

    int pixel = ((640 * y) + x);
    // Put 5 pixel values into a single 32-bit integer
    vga_data_array[pixel / 5] |= (color << (24 - ((pixel % 5) * 6)));
}

int main()
{
    stdio_init_all();
    PIO pio = pio0;

    uint hsync_offset = pio_add_program(pio, &hsync_program);
    uint vsync_offset = pio_add_program(pio, &vsync_program);
    uint rgb_offset = pio_add_program(pio, &rgb_program);

    uint hsync_sm = 0;
    uint vsync_sm = 1;
    uint rgb_sm = 2;

    hsync_program_init(pio, hsync_sm, hsync_offset, HSYNC);
    vsync_program_init(pio, vsync_sm, vsync_offset, VSYNC);
    rgb_program_init(pio, rgb_sm, rgb_offset, RED_PIN);

    int rgb_chan_0 = 0;
    int rgb_chan_1 = 1;

    dma_channel_config c0 = dma_channel_get_default_config(rgb_chan_0); // default configs
    channel_config_set_transfer_data_size(&c0, DMA_SIZE_32);            // 8-bit txfers
    channel_config_set_read_increment(&c0, true);                       // yes read incrementing
    channel_config_set_write_increment(&c0, false);                     // no write incrementing
    channel_config_set_dreq(&c0, DREQ_PIO0_TX2);                        // DREQ_PIO0_TX2 pacing (FIFO)
    channel_config_set_chain_to(&c0, rgb_chan_1);                       // chain to other channel

    dma_channel_configure(
        rgb_chan_0,        // Channel to be configured
        &c0,               // The configuration we just created
        &pio->txf[rgb_sm], // write address (RGB PIO TX FIFO)
        &vga_data_array,   // The initial read address (pixel color array)
        TXCOUNT,           // Number of transfers; in this case each is 4 bytes.
        false              // Don't start immediately.
    );

    // Channel One (reconfigures the first channel)
    dma_channel_config c1 = dma_channel_get_default_config(rgb_chan_1); // default configs
    channel_config_set_transfer_data_size(&c1, DMA_SIZE_32);            // 32-bit txfers
    channel_config_set_read_increment(&c1, false);                      // no read incrementing
    channel_config_set_write_increment(&c1, false);                     // no write incrementing
    channel_config_set_chain_to(&c1, rgb_chan_0);                       // chain to other channel

    dma_channel_configure(
        rgb_chan_1,                        // Channel to be configured
        &c1,                               // The configuration we just created
        &dma_hw->ch[rgb_chan_0].read_addr, // Write address (channel 0 read address)
        &address_pointer,                  // Read address (POINTER TO AN ADDRESS)
        1,                                 // Number of transfers, in this case each is 4 byte
        false                              // Don't start immediately.
    );

    pio_sm_put_blocking(pio, hsync_sm, H_ACTIVE);
    pio_sm_put_blocking(pio, vsync_sm, V_ACTIVE);
    pio_sm_put_blocking(pio, rgb_sm, RGB_ACTIVE);
    pio_enable_sm_mask_in_sync(pio, ((1u << hsync_sm) | (1u << vsync_sm) | (1u << rgb_sm)));
    dma_start_channel_mask((1u << rgb_chan_0));

    while (true)
    {
        int index = 0;
        int xcounter = 0;
        int ycounter = 0;

        for (int y = 0; y < 480; y++)
        {
            if (ycounter == 8)
            {
                ycounter = 0;
                index = (index + 1) % 64;
            }
            ycounter += 1;

            for (int x = 0; x < 640; x++)
            {
                if (xcounter == 10)
                {
                    xcounter = 0;
                    index = (index + 1) % 64;
                }

                xcounter += 1;
                drawPixel(x, y, index);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I changed the rgb.pio so that is should push out 6 bits 5 times per 32-uint that is pulled from the DMA.

```
.program rgb

pull block                  ; Pull RGB_ACTIVE from FIFO to OSR (only once)
mov y, osr                  ; Copy value from OSR to y scratch register
.wrap_target

set pins, 0                 ; Zero RGB pins in blanking
mov x, y                    ; Initialize counter variable

wait 1 irq 1 [3]            ; Wait for vsync active mode (starts 5 cycles after execution)

colorout:
    pull block              ; Pull color value 32-bits from DMA
    out pins, 6 [4]         ; Push 6 bits out to pins
    out pins, 6 [4]         ; Push 6 bits out to pins
    out pins, 6 [4]         ; Push 6 bits out to pins
    out pins, 6 [4]         ; Push 6 bits out to pins
    out pins, 6 [2]         ; Push 6 bits out to pins
    jmp x-- colorout        ; Stay here thru horizontal active mode
.wrap

% c-sdk {
static inline void rgb_program_init(PIO pio, uint sm, uint offset, uint pin) {
    pio_sm_config c = rgb_program_get_default_config(offset);
    sm_config_set_set_pins(&c, pin, 6);
    sm_config_set_out_pins(&c, pin, 6);
    for(int i=0; i<6;i++) {
        pio_gpio_init(pio, pin+i);
    }
    pio_sm_set_consecutive_pindirs(pio, sm, pin, 6, true);
    pio_sm_init(pio, sm, offset, &c);
}
%}
```

I think there is an issue with passing the pixel data to the DMA.

I also changed the size of the array from 153600 to 61440 (the amount of 32-bit integers I need to fit my 640x480x6 bits) and changed and the type from:

```c
unsigned char vga_data_array[TXCOUNT];
char * address_pointer = &vga_data_array[0];
```

To:

```c
uint32_t vga_data_array[TXCOUNT];
uint32_t *address_pointer = &vga_data_array[0];
```

I changed the RGB_ACTIVE constant from 319 ((horizontal active)/2 - 1
the original code crammed 2 colors in one byte) to 127 (640 pixels / 5 - 1) as I want to put 5 pixels into one 32-bit int.

In the original code drawPixel had:

```c
// Is this pixel stored in the first 3 bits
// of the vga data array index, or the second
// 3 bits? Check, then mask.
if (pixel & 1) {
    vga_data_array[pixel>>1] |= (color << 3);
}
else {
    vga_data_array[pixel>>1] |= (color);
}
```

I changed that to:

```c
// pixel divided by 5 to get the index I want to put 5 pixels into
// the 32-bit int. And some bit shifting to get the bits in the correct
// position.
vga_data_array[pixel / 5] |= (color << (24 - ((pixel % 5) * 6)));
```

I changed here is the configuration of the first DMA channel:

```c
dma_channel_config c1 = dma_channel_get_default_config(rgb_chan_1);   // default configs
    channel_config_set_transfer_data_size(&c1, DMA_SIZE_8);              // 8-bit txfers
```

To:

```c
dma_channel_config c1 = dma_channel_get_default_config(rgb_chan_1);   // default configs
    channel_config_set_transfer_data_size(&c1, DMA_SIZE_32);              // 32-bit txfers
```

Here is the original colorout:

```
colorout:
    pull block              ; Pull color value
    out pins, 3 [4]         ; Push out to pins (first pixel)
    out pins, 3 [2]         ; Push out to pins (next pixel)
    jmp x-- colorout        ; Stay here thru horizontal active mode
```

I just do not see what I'm doing wrong. The pixel array is correct, I tested it and with another resolution 640x350 it just works. What could be the problem?

Comment: Great explanation of what you are attempting.  Can you add something about what you have observed beyond _"it does not work"_,  or _"something must be wrong"_?  when you run in debug what to the intermediate states of the variables show?

Comment: Hi rryker, thanks for your comment. I added more information to my question about what I tried to do to make it work. I think it has something todo with the DMA configuration or something stupid I just don't see. I stared a long time at the code but I can't find what is wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have tools to debug the pico jet. I could buy a second pico to get that done but I don't have one now.

Comment: Would love the see the full source

Comment: @jimjag, sure here it is https://github.com/sandergroen/Raspberry-Pi-Pico-6-bit-VGA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running it in the Wokwi simulator I found out my pio programs use to many instructions the maximum is 32 per pio and I was using 35. So I reduced the pio program instructions by 3 and now everything works.

In the hsync.pio I removed the second set pins instruction and put a higher delay to the irq 0 instruction:

```
backporch:
    set pins, 1 [31]    ; High for back porch (32 cycles)
    ; set pins, 1 [12]    ; High for back porch (45 cycles)
    irq 0       [13]     ; Set IRQ to signal end of line (47 cycles)
```

In the vsync program I removed the set y, 9 and jmp instruction and added a delay of 7 to the set pins instruction of the sync pulse:

```
; FRONTPORCH
; set y, 9                          ;
frontporch:
    wait 1 irq 0       [2]           ;
    ; jmp y-- frontporch            ;

; SYNC PULSE
set pins, 0      [7]                 ; Set pin low
```

Comment: Great you got it to work but I have to ask why aren't you using 3 bytes (24 bits) to store your 6-bits per pixel? That way there is no wasted data (4 pixels fits into 3 bytes perfectly). 32-bits per 5 pixels is still wasting two bits.

Comment: Hi Dradge, thanks for your comment. That would be awesome! But I'm not sure if that is possible as DMA allows only to transfer 8, 16 or 32 bits to the pio program as far as i know. See the docs at https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation//pico-sdk/rp2__common_2hardware__dma_2include_2hardware_2dma_8h.html#rpipd7ae78f44a7d403342e5.

Answer (score 0):

I't seems that no need for 24 in line:

```
vga_data_array[pixel / 5] |= (color << (24 - ((pixel % 5) * 6)));
```

because it made mirror the characters.